# Azure Devops WorkItems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am new to azure devops and devops field. I am exploring myself in azure devops, where learning boards. I I was confused while updating the status of my work item. I was assigned with a task (example: create a login page. Now i went to azure boards and its allowing me to edit the title and priority fields. Those are already set by my higher levels. I only need to add details like time efforts, status). What security is our team missing to achieve this?

Also i need to move the work items from one stage to next stage(Todo to completed) via VS2017. How to achieve that. Now i am currently going to devops portal and drag and drop the workitems to next columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to edit a work item, you can edit any field on the work item. This is by design. Whether it's a limitation or not is up to you to decide.

You can update the work item state from Visual Studio by linking it to your commit in the team explorer. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-web-form#work-items-linked-to-git-code-development).

Comment: Thank you @daniel Mann.. why am i able to see other members work items in my board? is this a default behaviour or any settings we need to create for that?